# With Angular 2, how can I use ngFor data between different component files?

Tags: angular, typescript

With Angular 2, how can I use ngFor data between different component files?

For example I have this in playbar.component.ts file:

```
...
<audio 
 gFor="let audio of sources"                  
 #mediaOne 
 [vgMedia]="mediaOne" 
 id="mediaOne" 
 crossorigin
 [src]="currentItem.src">
...
```

and this in tunes.component.ts template I have (and have imported the above file)

```
...
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of sources; let $index = index"
        (click)="onClickPlaylistItem(item, $index)"
        [class.selected]="item === currentItem">
        {{ item.src }}
  </li>
</ul>
...
```

Sorry, I'm a bit of an Angular noob.

Answer (score 0):

To share data between components you can use a Service.

More info about it 
[here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

The service would have the data as observables and the 2 components would subscribe to the observables.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll check it out.

Comment: This is not required. They could share an array exported by a common dependency. Not a great idea, but nothing says that you _need_ a service, let alone one that uses observables.